# Cannot find controller class in route with auth class in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9

I have a page, where when user pick a date, choose data from dropdown, and click search.
The page which initialy have 0 data in its table, will be populated with data.
The query to fetch the data is inside a controller class.

I have successfully ran the page before. But I didn't use any authentication (auth) feature.
And now, when I use laravel breeze as the authentication starter. I got an error because the program cannot found my controller class.

Here's the previous route (web.php) code, without auth class.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\GetEmployeePerformance;
Route::get('/performance', [GetEmployeePerformance::class, 'index']);
require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

Here's the current route (web.php) code

```
use App\Http\Controllers\GetEmployeePerformance;
Route::get('/performance', function () {
    return view('performance', [GetEmployeePerformance::class, 'index']);
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('performance');
require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

And here's the controller's code

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class GetEmployeePerformance extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $performance_summary = [];
        $performance_detail = [];

        if (request('date')){ ...}
        return view('performance', compact('performance_summary','performance_detail'));
```

And this is how the value is called in view

```
<tbody>
    @for ($x = 0; $x < count($performance_summary); $x++)
    <tr>
    ...
```

This is error, the route failed to find the controller class.
[image]

Which parts should I fix?

Comment: your route isn't going to a controller, you are using a closure for your route

Comment: And how to fix it so that it can go to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the fix on my own.
I changed the route code, into this code below

```
Route::get('/performance', [GetEmployeePerformance::class,'index'])->middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->name('performance');
```

I hope this answer can help other people who have similar problem as me :D